# Why mMap.addMarker (...) and map.getMyLocation(); dont work and stop my app android?

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, google-maps

In sqlite the same method work, but I changed the database to Mysql, this method does not work!

i send arraylist(names) from  AsyncTask to show method in MapsActivity
and probleme in ligne
myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
and
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dz).title("welcome to")).showInfoWindow();

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
public void mark(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    LatLng dz = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dz).title("welcome to")).showInfoWindow();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dz, 16));
}

public float distanceBetween(Double latitude, Double longitude) {
    float result[] = new float[10];     
    Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
    Double mylatitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    Double mylongitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    myLocation.distanceBetween(mylatitude, mylongitude, latitude, longitude, result);
    return result[0];
}

 public void show ( ArrayList names) {
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrList = names;
        int c = arrList.size();
        Float t[] = new Float[10];
        Double company[] = new Double[3];

        if (c > 0) {
            int n = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while (c > 0) {
                Double latitude = Double.valueOf(arrList.get(n));
                Double longitude = Double.valueOf(arrList.get(n + 1));
                Double price = Double.valueOf(arrList.get(n + 2));

                t[i] = distanceBetween(latitude, longitude);

                if (n == 0) {
                    company[0] = latitude;
                    company[1] = longitude;
                    company[2] = price;
                }
                if ((i > 0) && (t[i] < t[i - 1])) {
                    t[i] = t[i - 1];
                    company[0] = latitude;
                    company[1] = longitude;
                    company[2] = price;
                }
                i = i + 1;
                n = n + 3;
                c = c - 3;
            }
            mark(company[0], company[1]);


        } else {
            Toast T = Toast.makeText(this, "product is not available ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            T.show();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "price of product = " + company[2], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
public class Parser2 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

    Context c;
    String data;


    ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<>();

    public Parser2(Context c, String data) {
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parse();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if(integer==1)
        {
            MapsActivity m =new MapsActivity();
            m.show(names);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(c,"Unable to Parse2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private int parse()
    {
        try
        {
            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray(data);
            JSONObject jo=null;

            names.clear();

            int i;
            for( i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
            {
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                String latitude=jo.getString("latitude");
                String longitude=jo.getString("longitude");
                String price=jo.getString("price");
                names.add(latitude);
                names.add(longitude);
                names.add(price);}
            return 1;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace of your app stopping.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.location.Location com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getMyLocation()' on a null object reference
  at com.example.mapproject.MapsActivity.distanceBetween(MapsActivity.java:156)
        at com.example.mapproject.MapsActivity.show(MapsActivity.java:184)    at com.example.mapproject.Parser2.onPostExecute(Parser2.java:43)
        at com.example.mapproject.Parser2.onPostExecute(Parser2.java:13)

Answer (score 2):

It seems the reason of the problem is because getMyLocation() is null and the algorithm is expecting it not to be null. Please make sure that this object contains value. You can use this code to check the last location of the user:

```
LocationManager service = (LocationManager) 

getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

Hope this information find you helpful and good luck on your project!